# Azure B2C - JWT Client assertion custom exception message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm able to access B2C Passwordreset policy with client assertion token and I've been trying to show custom error message instead of JWT default exception (**AADB2C90017**: **The client assertion provided in the request is invalid: 'client_secret' was used as the verification key**) when client assertion token gets expired. Can I customize this exception message in B2C policy only when expiry? If so, help required. Let me know incase any queries.

I've gone through api.Error, however it's for generic. Customize Message only when expiry of token.

[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP6e3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Set a custom error page UI (i.e. [the **api.error** content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#content-definition-ids))
- Use CSS to hide the default error message
- [Use JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) to parse the default error message and, if it contains "AADB2C90017", then show a custom error message